# Run script locally with remote dataset on AzureML

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a script that for development purposes I would like to run and debug locally. However, I do not want to store the data needed for my experiment on my local machine.

I am using the `azureml` library with the Azure Machine Learning Studio. See my code below

```
# General
import os
import argparse

# Data analysis and wrangling
import pandas as pd

# Machine learning
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from azureml.core import Run

# Get the environment of this run
run = Run.get_context()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--data_path',
        type=str,
        help='Path to the training data',
        # The default path is on my local machine, however I would like to reference a remote datastore on Azure as a parameter to this script
        default=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Obtain the data from the datastore
    train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.data_path, os.listdir(args.data_path)[0]))

    # Drop unnecessary columns
    train_df = train_df.drop(['Name', 'PassengerId', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)

    # Encode non-numeric features as dummies
    train_df = pd.get_dummies(train_df)

    # Drop NA's
    train_df.dropna(inplace=True)

    # Use gridsearch CV to find the best parameters for the model
    parameters = {'kernel': ('linear', 'rbf'),
                  'C': [1, 10]}

    # Initialize the grid search
    search = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=parameters, cv=8)

    # Train the model
    search.fit(train_df.drop("Survived", axis=1), train_df["Survived"])
```

Now, the script uses a local folder 'data'. However, I would like to give an argument to this script that indicates I would like to use a remote datastore in the Azure Machine Learning Studio. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

After some trying, I have found a way to do this, although I think there should/could be a better way.

Here I use `argparse` and an `azureml` function to directly read the data into memory (in this case a `pandas` dataframe).

Here's the code:

```
# General
import os
import argparse

# Data analysis and wrangling
import pandas as pd

# Machine learning
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Azure libraries
from azureml.core import Run, Workspace, Dataset

# Get the environment of this run
run = Run.get_context()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--data_path',
        type=str,
        help='Path to the training data',
        default='local'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.data_path == 'local':
        # Use the local folder
        data_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')
        train_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_path, os.listdir(data_path)[0]))
    elif args.data_path == 'remote':
        # Use the remote location

        # Get the workspace from the config file
        ws = Workspace.from_config()

        # Obtain the dataset
        datastore = ws.get_default_datastore()
        data_path = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=[(datastore,
                                                                'path_to_file')])

        # Read the data
        train_df = data_path.to_pandas_dataframe()
    else:
        # Unknown source, create empty dataframe
        data_path = "Unknown"
        train_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Drop unnecessary columns
    train_df = train_df.drop(['Name', 'PassengerId', 'Ticket', 'Cabin'], axis=1)

    # Encode non-numeric features as dummies
    train_df = pd.get_dummies(train_df)

    # Drop NA's
    train_df.dropna(inplace=True)

    # Use gridsearch CV to find the best parameters for the model
    parameters = {'kernel': ('linear', 'rbf'),
                  'C': [1, 10]}

    # Initialize the grid search
    search = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid=parameters, cv=8)

    # Train the model
    search.fit(train_df.drop("Survived", axis=1), train_df["Survived"])

    run.log_table(name='Gridsearch results', value=pd.DataFrame(search.cv_results_).to_dict(orient="list"))
```